# Calculating derivative?

Tags: derivatives

I'm new to "advanced maths" (I'm only 14), and I wonder what *derivative* is is and how I can calculate it. The problem I need this for is to calculate the *derivative* of an *aircraft's lift coefficient* for my flight simulation game, so I need to at least understand the basics. I've read a bit on wikipedia, but I find it a bit hard to understand when there is such amount of text, so I would really appreciate if someone could give a brief explaination of it.

**EDIT:** The formula that gives me the lift coefficient looks like this:

$$C_L = C_{L0} + C_{L\alpha} \cdot \alpha$$

where:

$C_{L0}$ is the lift coefficient when the angle of attack is 0. This value will be found on google for each aircraft.
$C_{L\alpha}$ is the derivative of the lift coefficient, which I want to calculate.
$\alpha$ is the angle of attack.

**EDIT 2:** Now I've read some basics about maths, and functions, and as I understand them, they are pretty similar to functions/methods in programming. You "input" a number/multiple numbers, the function affects/changes that number/those numbers, and "outputs" the changed number/numbers, right? So as I understand it, the function that gives the lift coefficient relative to the angle of attack looks like this:

$$f(C_{L0}, C_{L\alpha}) = C_{L0} + C_{L\alpha} \cdot a$$

Thanks!

// TheDDestroyer12

Comment: Do you have the function the gives your aircraft's lift coefficient?

Comment: @graydad The lift coefficient is tested/calculated by the aircraft manufacturer in a wind tunnel, so I'll have to google that for each aircraft. Also, to be honest, I don't really know what a function is in mathatics. I google specific things that I need to know, so I haven't learned that yet, but I'll add the formula that gives the lift coefficient relative to the angle of attack, to my question!

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 A derivative is an operation in calculus that gives the instantaneous slope of a function.  If you do not even know what a function is, then you will never understand what a derivative actually is. I would suggest actually not just googling the concepts you need, but actually learning about the fundamentals you need to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to do that. Thanks.

Comment: @MathN00b Okay, now I have read a bit and have an understanding of functions.